# Create XSD element with specific name but any structure

Tags: xsd, jaxb

I am trying to create one internal element in my XSD that will render different types of XMLs

So expected XML structure will be like:

```
<root>
 <something>
 <specificName> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> etc </specificName>
 </something>
</root>
```

When I am using xs:any, the generated Java Class contains this

[image]

I want the **name** of the element to be **specified**, but to be of anyType.

The issue is that every element I am trying to set in the "any" element, is *appended*, rather than set, creating this XML structure:

```
<root>
 <something>
 <any> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> etc </any>
 </something> 
</root>
```

I want either:

1. To let JaxB know somehow (by bindings?) that the element name will be set to "specificName"
2. Ignore "any" element during the deserialization

PS: I know xs:anyType addresses the issue, but I want specifically to show that I will use any Namespace for this element with lax process context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you answered yourself. You'll need an element which contains the any:

```
public class SpecificName {

   @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
   private Object any;

   ...
}

public class Something {

   @XmlElement
   private SpecificName specificName;

   ...
}
```

Note that having a second XML declaration as your example suggests doesn't work.